# Estabilishing a WebSocket connection with Strophe.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, xmpp, strophe

I have set up a simple BOSH and WebSocket server using `node-xmpp-bosh` like this:

```
const nxb = require("node-xmpp-bosh");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5280;

const server_options = {
  port: PORT,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  path: '/http-bind/',
  logging: 'INFO'
};

const bosh_server = nxb.start_bosh(server_options);
const ws_server = nxb.start_websocket(bosh_server, server_options);
```

I've deployed this server to Heroku and now I'm trying to create an XMPP connection with Strophe using it.

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection(
  "wss://votebot-web-app-bosh.herokuapp.com/http-bind/",
  {protocol: "wss"}
);

conn.connect(...);
```

If I open the browser dev tools, I can see there's a GET request to `wss://votebot-web-app-bosh.herokuapp.com/http-bind/` with the HTTP status code `101 Switching Protocols`, but there's no response.

Indeed, the Heroku logs show this error:

```
[2017-06-09 20:10:17.359] [WARN] [xmpp-proxy-connector.js:Object.stanza:138] - WEBSOCKET d99abd10-683a-485c-a1b8-21f960418523 bosh-stanza - stream not available
```

I am stuck here so I was wondering if anyone that has already used XMPP over WebSockets could give me any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Edit: In case it matters, I forgot to add that I can successfully connect to the BOSH service in the same URL (`https://votebot-web-app-bosh.herokuapp.com/http-bind/`).

Answer (score 0):

If your server listens on port process.env.PORT or 5280, the client must connect to port process.env.PORT or port 5280.

```
    "wss://votebot-web-app-bosh.herokuapp.com/http-bind/",
```

wss = port 443 unless you specify another one.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried specifying the port in Strophe as well. The problem is that Heroku doesn't give you a fixed port; it gives you a different one each time you launch the app. I did add a line at the bottom of the bosh/ws server so that I know which port it was listening on, in order to add it to the Strophe connection URL (``"wss://votebot-web-app-bosh.herokuapp.com:53721/http-bind/"``). However, I just get a "can't estabilish a connection to the server" error when trying to connect. Thanks for the answer.